# curl http request to node-red

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, node-red

I'm very very new to node-red and don't know a thing about sending a http request to node-red. I've been trying out this method to send request to node-red but it gave me status code 0.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://my.node.com:port/endpoint", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
     data: "data"
}));
console.log(xhr.status);
```

My senior suggested me to use the curl command - and I have no idea how to do that. I'm not used to using curl nor have time to spend to explore deeply as I have limited time available. I attempted to use this method but is returned with error `msg undefined`

```
msg.payload = "data to post";
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
return msg;
```

How can I send http request to node-red?

Comment: Please read the documentation for XMLHttpRequest, it is Asynchronous, so checking the status like that will not work. Also I assume the suggestion to use curl is an independent way to test the endpoint with a HTTP client known to work.

Comment: Also you appear to have set `msg.payload` to a string, not JSON so the content-type is wrong

Comment: When you said "an independent way" does that mean it's also possible to use XMLHttpRequest/fetch to send the request to node-red?

Comment: I mean using something other than your web app to test that your Node-RED flow is doing what expect